# Annoying switched controls on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On minecraft, a recent update caused my controls to switch. It is different from a past update where you could swap them in options (jump and crouch) as I can't find anything to fix it. The update made this happen: When i joined my sister on a server straight after updating the game, when I moved the screen up, the screen went down and the person looked at the floor, and vice versa. Does anybody know how to fix this, because it is REALLY annoying!

Comment: This does not sound like an issue with PC Minecraft. Are you playing Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 3):

Go to controls and turn <kbd>Invert Mouse</kbd> to `OFF`:

[image: Invert mouse option]

Comment: lol that was easy.